# Arranging an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that I'd like to rearrange in a certain format.

```
array:4 [▼
  "ROWID" => array:3 [▼
    0 => 0
    1 => 1
    2 => 2
  ]
  "First Name" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "BILLY"
    1 => "SALLY"
    2 => "TYLER"
  ]
  "Last Name" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "RAY"
    1 => "SUE"
    2 => "TERRIER"
  ]
  "Middle Name" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "B."
    1 => "S."
    2 => "T."
  ]
]
```

How can I arrange the array so it looks like this:

```
array:4 [▼
  "ROWID" => array:3 [▼
    0 => 0
    1 => 1
    2 => 2
  ]
  "First Name" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "BILLY"
    1 => "SALLY"
    2 => "TYLER"
  ]
  "Middle Name" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "B."
    1 => "S."
    2 => "T."
  ]
  "Last Name" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "RAY"
    1 => "SUE"
    2 => "TERRIER"
  ]
]
```

Where Last Name and Middle Name arrays switch positions? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It's an associative array, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I've added an answer for you. Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/52840710/1138192

Answer (score 1):

Try like this way to rearrange your **$existing_array** to **$expected_array** format by simple tweaking/switching the array element by index like `$existing_array['Middle Name']` and `$existing_array['Last Name']`.

```
<?php
$existing_array =  ["ROWID" =>[0 => 0,1 => 1,2 => 2],
  "First Name" => [0 => "BILLY",1 => "SALLY",2 => "TYLER"],
  "Last Name" => [0 => "RAY",1 => "SUE",2 => "TERRIER"],
  "Middle Name" =>[0 => "B.",1 => "S.",2 => "T."]];

$expected_array = ['ROWID'=>$existing_array['ROWID'],'First Name'=>$existing_array['First Name'],'Middle Name'=>$existing_array['Middle Name'],'Last Name'=>$existing_array['Last Name']];
print_r($expected_array);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/GlqXk

Comment: @Ice76 true, but that is an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom sort by key, something like this. It can also be changed and adjusted easily.

```
$ranking = array(
    'ROWID',
    'First Name',
    'Middle Name',
    'Last Name'
);

uksort( $name, function ( $a, $b ) use ( $ranking ) {
    return array_search ( $a, $ranking ) < array_search ( $b, $ranking ) ? -1 : 1;
} );
```

Here is the demo: [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/XmRlU)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check this documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php

Using Array replace function from php, you can swap the value of array using the key, example

```
$array = ["a","b","c"];
$change1 = array(0 => "d");
$try = array_replace($array,$change1);
//expected result
$array = ["a","b","d"];
```

And in your case,

```
$array = ["ROWID[]", "First Name[]", "Last Name[]", "Middle Name[]"]
$change1 = array(2 => Middle Name[], 3 => Last Name[])
$result = array_replace($array,$change1)
```

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
"ROWID" => array(
    0 => 0,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 2
),
"First Name" => array(
    0 => "BILLY",
    1 => "SALLY",
    2 => "TYLER"
),
"Last Name" => array(
    0 => "RAY",
    1 => "SUE",
    2 => "TERRIER"
),
"Middle Name" => array(
    0 => "B.",
    1 => "S.",
    2 => "T."
  )
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
if ($key == 'Last Name') {
    $temp = $arr[$key];
    unset($arr[$key]);
    $arr['Last Name'] = $temp;
 }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
'ROWID' => 
   array (size=3)
     0 => int 0
     1 => int 1
     2 => int 2
'First Name' => 
   array (size=3)
     0 => string 'BILLY' (length=5)
     1 => string 'SALLY' (length=5)
     2 => string 'TYLER' (length=5)
'Middle Name' => 
   array (size=3)
     0 => string 'B.' (length=2)
     1 => string 'S.' (length=2)
     2 => string 'T.' (length=2)
'Last Name' => 
   array (size=3)
     0 => string 'RAY' (length=3)
     1 => string 'SUE' (length=3)
     2 => string 'TERRIER' (length=7)
```